# wp_list_categories to show categories for current post

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, wp-list-categories

I want to show only categories name and link of the current post page.
For example i have a post lets say "test123" and I have linked the post with 2 categories "ab","bc". However I have 5 different categories. So I want to show only 2 categories "ab","bc" when user goes to the "test123" page.

Please see my code below it is showing all the categories but I want to show only categories which are linked with the current post page.

```
wp_list_categories( 'number=5' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php the_category(); ?>
```

or, if you want more options:

```
<?php the_category( $separator, $parents, $post_id ); ?>
```

This will do the trick.  It can also be used like this:

```
<?php $catArr = get_the_category( $id ); ?>
```

Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_category
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category